# My simple HTTPS Java server does not receive form's POST data

Tags: java, html, jakarta-ee, post

With much efforts, I finally was able to write a simple HTTPS server in Java to handle HTTPS requests. What I eventually should do is to get the data from the form, process it, and return the results back. Just as a start, in this simple example I just want to return the "value" of the submitted option. Unfortunately when I'm printing what the server has received, I don't see any POST data except `POST /run.html HTTP/1.1`. What is the problem, and how can I add this feature into it?

PS: don't forget to create a keystore for the SSL and write the info in the code if you want to test.

The POST request I get is this (even the length is 41, which I guess should be correct for a missing data of `list=capacity.3Mbps_400RTT_PER_0.0001.txt`):

```
POST /run.html HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Referer: https://localhost:8888/
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: localhost:8888
Content-Length: 41
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Here is my simple form in HTML (which actually I'm supposed to receive its HTML source from server):

```
<html><body>
<p>
<h3> Please select a configuration below to run the emulator.</h3>
<form action="run.html" method="POST">
<select name="list">

  <option name="400" value="capacity.3Mbps_400RTT_PER_0.0001.txt">capacity.3Mbps_400RTT_PER_0.0001</option>
  <option name="100" value="capacity.3Mbps_100RTT_PER_0.00001.txt">capacity.3Mbps_100RTT_PER_0.00001</option>
  <option name="200" value="capacity.3Mbps_200RTT_PER_0.0001.txt">capacity.3Mbps_200RTT_PER_0.0001</option>

</select>
<input type="submit" value="Run Emulator!">
</form>

</body></html>
```

Here is my Java HTTPS server program:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.security.KeyStore;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;

public class HttpsServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String ksName = "myJKS.jks";
        char ksPass[] = "key".toCharArray();
        char ctPass[] = "key".toCharArray();
        try {

//          Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad");
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            ks.load(new FileInputStream(ksName), ksPass);
            KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            kmf.init(ks, ctPass);
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
            SSLServerSocketFactory ssf = sc.getServerSocketFactory();
            SSLServerSocket s = (SSLServerSocket) ssf.createServerSocket(8888,0, null);

            System.out.println("Server started:");
            printServerSocketInfo(s);
            // Listening to the port
            int count = 0;
            while (true) {
                SSLSocket c = (SSLSocket) s.accept();
                // Someone is calling this server
                count++;
                System.out.println("Connection #: " + count);
                // printSocketInfo(c);
                BufferedWriter w = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                        c.getOutputStream()));
                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        c.getInputStream()));
                String m = r.readLine();
                System.out.println(m);
//              w.write(m);
                if (m != null) {
                    // We have a real data connection
                    w.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
                    w.newLine();
                    w.write("Content-Type: text/html");
                    //should be two new lines!!!
                    w.newLine();
                    w.newLine();
                    if(m.contains("GET"))
                    //read from file
                    MyFileReader(w,"index.html");

                    while ((m = r.readLine()) != null) {
                        if (m.length() == 0)
                            break; // End of a GET call
//                      w.write(m);
                        System.out.println(m);
                        w.newLine();
                    }
                    w.flush();
                }
                w.close();
                r.close();
                c.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void MyFileReader(BufferedWriter w, String uri) {
        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {

            String sCurrentLine;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(uri));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                w.write(sCurrentLine);
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)
                    br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void printSocketInfo(SSLSocket s) {
        System.out.println("Server socket class: " + s.getClass());
        System.out.println("   Remote address = "
                + s.getInetAddress().toString());
        System.out.println("   Remote port = " + s.getPort());
        System.out.println("   Local socket address = "
                + s.getLocalSocketAddress().toString());
        System.out.println("   Local address = "
                + s.getLocalAddress().toString());
        System.out.println("   Local port = " + s.getLocalPort());
    }

    private static void printServerSocketInfo(SSLServerSocket s) {
        System.out.println("Server socket class: " + s.getClass());
        System.out.println("   Socker address = "
                + s.getInetAddress().toString());
        System.out.println("   Socker port = " + s.getLocalPort());
        System.out.println("   Need client authentication = "
                + s.getNeedClientAuth());
        System.out.println("   Want client authentication = "
                + s.getWantClientAuth());
        System.out.println("   Use client mode = " + s.getUseClientMode());
    }
}
```

Comment: Could the second line of your request be blank? That would cause you to break inside if your inner while loop and not print out any of the other lines.

Comment: No, I don't think so. When it is not null and is the post method, it will go inside the loop and I will get the result.

Comment: @jlars62 I was just checking, and no...after POST /run.html HTTP/1.1 I do not have the form's data.

Comment: There is blank line after the headers and before the response body. And because that line is blank you are breaking out of your inner while loop. Just try removing this and see what happens `if (m.length() == 0)
                            break; // End of a GET call`

Comment: yeah; this is what I did. Seems after that blank line, there is null as opposed to bring data!

Comment: `int x=20;
while (x-->0) {    
m=r.readLine();      System.out.println(m);
w.newLine();
}`

Comment: What gets printed? `null`?

Answer (score 0):

How are you handling the POST method in your server? I see you have this portion for the GET method, looks like you need to add an else/if statement for POST method.

```
if(m.contains("GET")) {
  // return page HTML
} else if(m.contains("POST")) {
  // process form data
  // return page HTML
}
```

Comment: I don't do anything at this moment. Well, I don't see any data from the form to play with!